# Validar campos em um formulário feito com jQuery-steps

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

O formulário possui dois *steps*, consegui validar o primeiro step utilizando o *onStepChanging*. Porém no segundo *step* onde existem campos que precisam ser validados, a ação do usuário passa a ser o submit, que eu informo no *onFinished*. Tentei então no *onFinished* fazer a mesma validação que faço no *onStepChanging*, mas a variável não é preenchida utilizando o *val();* pois o form ainda não foi enviado. De que forma consigo validar os campos?

```js
$(function(){
    $("#form-total").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        enableAllSteps: true,
        autoFocus: true,
        transitionEffectSpeed: 700,
        titleTemplate : '<span class="title">#title#</span>',
        labels: {
            previous : 'Voltar',
            next : 'Próximo',
            finish : 'Enviar',
            current : ''
        },
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
            var nota = $('#nota').val();
            
            $('#nota-val').text('Sua no foi '+nota+'!');            
   
            //Valida se a nota foi preenchida
            if(nota == null){
                alert("Escolha uma nota!");
            return false;
            }

            return true;
},
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                $("#form").submit();
    }
});
});
```

```html
<form id="form" class="form-register" action="envia.php?at=<?echo $atendimento;?>" method="post">
 <div id="form-total">
  <!-- SECTION 1 -->
        <h2>1</h2>
        <section>  
            <div class="inner">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-holder">
      <select required class="form-control" name="nota" id="nota" required="">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma nota</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="7">7</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="0">0</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
        </section>
        <!-- SECTION 2 -->
        <h2>2</h2>
        <section>
            <div class="inner">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-holder shadow-textarea">
     <div id="nota-val"></div><br><div id="pergunta-val"></div><br>
     <select name="classificacao[]" id="classificacao[]" class="mdb-select md-form" multiple>         
       <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha</option>           
        <? while (($exibe = oci_fetch_array($parsed_classif, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
                                $NR_SEQUENCIA   = $exibe ['NR_SEQUENCIA'];
                                $DS_CLASSIFICACAO  = $exibe ['DS_CLASSIFICACAO'];
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?=$NR_SEQUENCIA?>"><?=$DS_CLASSIFICACAO?></option>
                            <? } ?>
      </select>
      <!--<br><br><textarea class="form-control z-depth-1" id="justificativa" placeholder="Justifique" style="width:300px;" ></textarea>-->
      <br><br><input type="text" id="justificativa" name="justificativa" placeholder="Justifique" class="form-control">
     </div>        
    </div>
   </div>
        </section>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na Validação o valor está vindo vazio e não nulo,

altere para

```
if(nota == null || nota ==''){
```

Vejá no código abaixo:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#form-total").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        enableAllSteps: true,
        autoFocus: true,
        transitionEffectSpeed: 700,
        titleTemplate : '<span class="title">#title#</span>',
        labels: {
            previous : 'Voltar',
            next : 'Próximo',
            finish : 'Enviar',
            current : ''
        },
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
            var nota = $('#nota').val();
            
            $('#nota-val').text('Sua no foi '+nota+'!');            
          
            //Valida se a nota foi preenchida
            if(nota == null || nota ==''){
                alert("Escolha uma nota!");
            return false;
            }

            return true;
},
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                $("#form").submit();
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.js"></script>

<form id="form" class="form-register" action="envia.php?at=<?echo $atendimento;?>" method="post">
 <div id="form-total">
  <!-- SECTION 1 -->
        <h2>1</h2>
        <section>  
            <div class="inner">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-holder">
      <select required class="form-control" name="nota" id="nota" required="">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma nota</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="7">7</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="0">0</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
        </section>
        <!-- SECTION 2 -->
        <h2>2</h2>
        <section>
            <div class="inner">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-holder shadow-textarea">
     <div id="nota-val"></div><br><div id="pergunta-val"></div><br>
     <select name="classificacao[]" id="classificacao[]" class="mdb-select md-form" multiple>         
       <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha</option>           
        <? while (($exibe = oci_fetch_array($parsed_classif, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
                                $NR_SEQUENCIA   = $exibe ['NR_SEQUENCIA'];
                                $DS_CLASSIFICACAO  = $exibe ['DS_CLASSIFICACAO'];
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?=$NR_SEQUENCIA?>"><?=$DS_CLASSIFICACAO?></option>
                            <? } ?>
      </select>
      <!--<br><br><textarea class="form-control z-depth-1" id="justificativa" placeholder="Justifique" style="width:300px;" ></textarea>-->
      <br><br><input type="text" id="justificativa" name="justificativa" placeholder="Justifique" class="form-control">
     </div>        
    </div>
   </div>
        </section>
 </div>
</form>
```